# equality of natural transformations?

Tags: category-theory

Sean $F,G:C\longrightarrow{D}$ dos funtores.

Ahora sean dos transformaciones naturales $r, s:F\longrightarrow{G}$.

Preguntas:

Cuándo $r$ y $s$ son isomorfos ? quiero una definición usando objetos o flechas.

Cuándo $r=s$ ?

Siempre  una aplicación entre funtores  $t:F\longrightarrow{G}$ es transformación natural ?

Gracias

---

Hi.

Let $F,G:C\longrightarrow{D}$ be two functors.

Now let $r, s:F\longrightarrow{G}$ be two natural transformations

Questions:

When are $ r $ and $ s $ are isomorphic? I want a definition using objects or arrows.

When is $ r = s $?

Always an application between functors $t:F\longrightarrow{G}$ is natural transformation?

Comment: Please, do **not** write your message in your native language. The english version is enough, and it is ok if your english is not perfect. Most of us aren't native english speakers anyway, so we will be indulgent as we hope others will be with us.

Comment: Por mi no hay problema que dejes tus aportaciones en español-

Answer (score 4):

In *any* category, two objects, $A$ and $B$, are isomorphic iff there exists two arrows, $h$ and $k$, such that $h\circ k = id_A$ and $k \circ h = id_B$. The definition of "isomorphic" is always the same. What changes is the category it's being applied to.

However, natural transformations are not normally considered objects of a category and you haven't specified a category, so it doesn't make sense to ask when two natural transformations are isomorphic. You could trivially turn a set of natural transformations into a discrete category at which point they'd be isomorphic iff they are equal.

Category theory is usually formulated within some ambient set theory, and that set theory usually has a global notion of equality. Nevertheless, we can be a bit more specific. Two natural transformations are equal iff they are equal component-wise. In symbols, $$r = s \iff \forall A\in\mathsf{Ob}(\mathcal{C}).r_A = s_A$$ $r_A$ and $s_A$ are arrows of $\mathcal{D}$ and when arrows are equal is information you provide when you define a category (assuming you aren't just relying on a global notion of equality).

Comment: This answer is correct, but let me add that a natural transformation $r:F\to G$ is, by definition, a function from objects of $C$ to morphisms in $D$. So the criterion for equality of two natural transformations is a special case of the general criterion for equality of functions: the domains are the same, and the values at each element of the domain are equal.  I mention this so that the OP doesn't get the impression that there's something arbitrary or ad hoc or specifically category-theoretic about the definition of equality of natural transformations.

Comment: To add even more on Andreas Blass's comment, natural transformations $F \to G$ are exactly the functors from $C$ to the arrow category of $D$ that restricts to $F$ and $G$ respectively along the selection of domain and codomain. Hence, there actually *is* a natural definition of isomorphic natural transformations: $r,s : F \to G$ are isomorphic if there exists natural isomorphisms $\theta : F \to F$ and $\tau : G \to G$ such that $\tau \circ r = s \circ \theta$.